# Django ImageField in TestCase

Tags: python, django, testcase

I try to create test in dgango TestCase.
I have this model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Изображение", upload_to='article_image')
```

and i have test class:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.admin = User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@admin.ru', 'admin')
    self.article_category = ArticleCategory.objects.create(title='ФИОЛЕТОВАЯ ПУДРА', slug='vneityiya')

def test_post(self):
    client = Client()
    client.login(**{'username': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'})
    response = client.post(self.url, data={
       'bundledarticleadminform-title': 'some title',
       'bundledarticleadminform-image': SOMETHING,
    })
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

I've got response 200 instead 302, because required image field. String like 'image.jpg' dont work. Maybe someone faced a similar task

Comment: It works with 'bundledarticleadminform-image': (self.file_name, open(self.file_name, 'rb')), just my file been empty, because this was an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use `client = Client(follow=True)` and `response.redirect_chain`. [More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get).